# Can I get the current page sourcecode from a firefox extension?

Tags: firefox, xul

Can this be done? How?

---

I want to write my own extension. Can Get the current page sorcecode in my own extension?

Answer (score 5):

As Rich says, adding `view-source` in front of the URL will give you the current page's source code. A keyboard shortcut for this is `Ctrl+U`.

> I want to write my own extension.

There are a number of existing Firefox extensions that fetch a page's source code and apply some action to it (colour-coding, syntax-checking, etc). Downloading them and looking at how they handle it may be a good place to start!

- [7 Firefox extensions to explore source code](http://www.searchenginejournal.com/7-firefox-extensions-to-explore-page-source-code/7375/)
- [View Formatted Source extension](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/697)

If you're new to Firefox extension development, [this article at Lifehacker](http://lifehacker.com/software/programming/how-to-build-a-firefox-extension-264490.php) is an excellent primer in how to start, and will give you an idea of where to look in the above linked extensions for tasks that may be similar to your own.

Answer (score 2):

Sure, just add view-source: in front of the URL.

```
view-source:http://stackoverflow.com/posts/edit/145419
```

Will show the source of this page for instance - try it in the address bar.